# Why TextOut in Canvas connects Box-Drawing Characters with a gap when I print them not sequentially in one statement?

Tags: delphi, canvas, textout

I use the fonts "Consolas" and/or "Courier New" in a project to draw an MS-DOS-looking environment. In this project if I use TextOut (of the TCanvas) to print for Box Drawing characters sequentially in one statement, everything is fine, for example it prints "────────" but if I address each character to print them separately, there would be a gap between each character, something like this: "-----------".
Here is an example for you to test it manually:

```
  ...

  Canvas.Font.Size := 12;

  w := Canvas.TextWidth('╬');
  h := Canvas.TextHeight('╬');

  Canvas.TextOut(100, 100, '╬╬');

  Canvas.TextOut(100, 100 + h, '╬');
  Canvas.TextOut(100 + w, 100 + h, '╬');

  Canvas.TextOut(100, 100 + h * 2, '╬');
  Canvas.TextOut(100 + w, 100 + h * 2, '╬');
```

The output is:

[image: Screenshot of output: white characters on a blue background. While the first line has connected characters, the remaining lines each display a very small gap between the characters.]

As you can see, vertically they are connected fine but horizontally there is a gap.

How can I fix it? Note that I draw what I want in an array, and then a procedure prints the array as follows:

```
  th := Canvas.TextHeight('A');
  tw := Canvas.TextWidth('A');
  for i := 0 to MaxWidth - 1 do
    for j := 0 to MaxHeight - 1 do
    begin
      Canvas.Brush.Color := fChars[i, j].BGColor;
      Canvas.Font.Color := fChars[i, j].FGColor;
      Canvas.TextOut(i * tw, j * th, fChars[i, j].Character);
    end;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the implications of using Canvas.TextOut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968771/what-are-the-implications-of-using-canvas-textout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `DrawText()` instead of `Canvas.TextOut()` it works.
The reason is explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32024892/800214). It is related to character kerning applied by the different windows API's on certain fonts.

here is a full working example:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
        FFont: TFont;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type TMyChar = record
  BGColor : TColor;
  FGColor : TColor;
  Character : Char;
end;

const
  FWidth : Integer = 9;
  FHeight : Integer = 9;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Fchars : Array[0..9,0..9] of TMyChar;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

var
 i,j : Integer;

begin
  Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
  Canvas.Font.Name := 'Courier New';
  for i := 0 to FWidth do
    for j := 0 to FHeight do
    begin
     FChars[i,j].Character:= '╬';
     FChars[i,j].BGColor := clBlue;
     FChars[i,j].FGColor := clYellow;
    end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
 FFont.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var w,h,i,j: Integer;
    FRect : TRect;
begin
  h := Canvas.TextHeight('A');
  w := Canvas.TextWidth('A');
  for i := 0 to FWidth do
    for j := 0 to FHeight do
    begin
      Canvas.Brush.Color := fChars[i, j].BGColor;
      Canvas.Font.Color := fChars[i, j].FGColor;
//      Canvas.TextOut(i * w, j * h, fChars[i, j].Character);
      FRect := Rect(i * w, j * h, i * w + w, j * h + h);
      DrawText(Canvas.Handle, (fChars[i, j].Character), 2, FRect, DT_LEFT);
    end;
  end;

end.
```

Comment: You don't need to abandon `TCanvas` if you don't want to: you can use its `TextRect` method.

Comment: Thanks. This works although it is much slower when the array is 150 x 50.